# Calculating the probability of data loss of a RAID 1+0 system

Tags: computer-architecture

I have a task where a RAID 1+0 system (A RAID 0 connects two RAID 1's with two disks each = makes 4 disks in total) is given with no further details. Then let p be the probability that one disk shows signs of failure. The variable p is not further defined.

Now I've received the task to calculate the probability that there will be a data loss in this RAID 1+0 system and I have literally no idea how solve this. I know that RAID 1+0 systems can cope with failure of the 1st and 3rd disk without having any data loss.

Please enlighten me, thanks!

Comment: "I have literally no idea how solve this" really doesn't help us. What parts don't you understand. Do you understand how RAID 1+0 works? Do you understand how to calculate probabilities in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A RAID 1 system with two disks fails if both disks fails. If each disk fails with probability $p$, then this happens with probability $p^2$.

The RAID 1+0 system fails if any of the two RAID 1 component systems fails. Since each of them fails with probability $p^2$, the probability that either fails is $2p^2 - p^4$ (using inclusion-exclusion).

In symbols, let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ be the failure status of the disks, that is, $x_i$ is true if the $i$th disk failed. The entire system fails if
$$ (x_1 \land x_2) \lor (x_3 \land x_4). $$
The variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are independent $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$ random variables. A short calculation (given above) shows that
$$ \Pr[(x_1 \land x_2) \lor (x_3 \land x_4)] = 2p^2 - p^4. $$

You can solve all similar questions in the same way.